# Twilio XML Validation warning 12200

Tags: javascript, xml, twilio, twilio-twiml

Our node.js app switched to using a bi-directional stream and since then, we are receiving this warning:

```
Msg "XML Validation warning"
line    "1"
parserMessage   " Element 'Stream' must have no character or element information item [children]"
ErrorCode   "12200"
cols    "278"
url "https://687e10954f9f.ngrok.io/api"
LogLevel    "WARN"
```

Twilio receives an xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Connect>
        <Stream name="Communication with Goodbot" url="wss://687e10954f9f.ngrok.io/ws">
            <Parameter name="Joe" value="Jones"/>
        </Stream>
    </Connect>
</Response>
```

It seems that the parameters are to blame since sending the same response without the `Parameter` tag generates no warnings. The app is working as expected, it's just that there is a bunch of warnings generated. Should we put the parameters somewhere else or is this a TWIML bug? We need to pass in custom parameters for our app to work.

Comment: Hey, I'm a developer evangelist at Twilio. I'm not sure of the answer here, but I've asked the team and will hopefully get a response to you soon.